# Is it possible to insert a count in the center of a Java println statement?

Tags: java, count, println

I am new to java and working on a Tip Calculator where I need a counter to determine the tip outcome if there are multiple customers splitting a check.

The output question is stated as

"What was customer  1's bill amount (in dollars)?"

If the user is to enter that there is more than one customer, How would I change the statement to have the output of

"What was customer 2's bill amount (in dollars)?

and so on and so forth.

I have tried to input the counter in the center of my statement to increase the number by one but I keep getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = i;
System.out.println("What was customer "+count+"'s bill amount (in dollars)?");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate your output:
Say you're counter is an integer called count

```
System.out.println("What was customer " + count + "'s bill amount (in dollars)?");
```

Comment: How in the world did you manage to use "your" correctly the first time, but then change it to "you're" for the second one?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) which can write formatted `String` similar to [c](/questions/tagged/c)

```
System.out.printf("What was customer %d's bill amount (in dollars) ?", count);
```

Comment: This is how you _should_ do it in Java 6+

Answer (score 0):

To add something more,you can also make the String using a **StringBuilder**:

```
StringBuilder builder  = new StringBuilder(String.format("What was customer %d's bill amount (in dollars)?", count));

    System.out.println(builder);
```

Comment: The `StringBuilder` is totally redundant here; you can just cut the `String.format(...)` inside `System.out.println(...)`. Or better, use `System.out.printf(...)` as suggested by @TAsk.

Comment: yes i know,but i just wanted to give something more..thanks for comment.